# How to delete duplicate data as per key value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help. I need to remove duplicate data as per key value using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$orginalArr = array(
  array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Raj"),
  array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Raj"),
  array("id"=>2,"name"=>"Ram"),
  array("id"=>2,"name"=>"Ram"),
  array("id"=>3,"name"=>"Rahul")
);
echo json_encode($orginalArr);
```

Here I need to remove the data as per `id`, meaning if `id` value is same then one set of data will be removed. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through values and push it to the new array. 

Example:

```
<?php
$orginalArr=array(array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Raj"),array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Raj"),array("id"=>2,"name"=>"Ram"),array("id"=>2,"name"=>"Ram"),array("id"=>3,"name"=>"Rahul"));

$newArray = array(); 

foreach ( $orginalArr as $arr )
    $newArray[$arr['id']] = array(
        'id' => $arr['id'], 
        'name' => $arr['name']); 



echo json_encode(array_values($newArray));
?>
```